# Zend Framework Plugins Location & Name

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been trying to create my own plugins and so far nothing seems to work for me, let's assume I am going to have my plugins directory under the application folder, which I think is the default location:

```
 application/plugins/WhosOnline.php
```

The contents of my plugin:

```
Class My_Plugin_WhosOnline extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract

{
     public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

       echo 'I have reached the plugin';
           exit;

     }
}
```

How exactly do I register this plugin in the application.ini file? I have tried:

```
 resources.frontController.plugins.whosonline = "My_Plugin_WhosOnline"
```

I have also tried:

```
 resources.frontController.plugins[] = "My_Plugin_WhosOnline"
```

I get the error:

```
 Class 'My_Plugin_WhosOnline' not found
```

How can I match those paths?? Do I have to create the directory **application/plugins/My/Plugin/** and then put the WhosOnline.php file there? Do I have to register the namespace My_Plugin? If so, how do I do that? Please help! I know this question has been asked before but I need someone to explain it to me much slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a lot with it I ended up doing the following, I added these to my application.ini:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyPlugins_"
resources.frontController.plugins.WhosOnline = "MyPlugins_WhosOnline"
```

Then I created a folder called **MyPlugins** inside the **library** folder and then I created my plugin file, called **WhosOnline.php** with the contents:

```
    Class MyPlugins_WhosOnline extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
    { 
        public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

            echo 'I have reached the plugin';
            exit;

        }   
    }
```

I finally got it working!

Answer (score 2):

If the plugin is located in `application/plugins/WhosOnline.php`, then the default class name for a Zend Application would be `Application_Plugin_WhosOnline`.

If your appnamespace is something other than `Application`, then that would be the prefix for your class.

If you want the class to be called `My_Plugin_WhosOnline`, create a folder called `My` in the `library` folder with a subfolder called `Plugin` (not plugins), and put the file there and add `Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');` to your Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct just add the following in your application.ini

appnamespace = "My"